# Android 13 emulator shows a black screen after choosing the video from the ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, kotlin, file, android-intent, android-13

I am using the android app and trying to add the gallery videos to my video editing screen. But it failed to show the video and showing a black screen.

Can any one let me know what I am doing wrong.

I am click on the gallery icon and try to open the video from the ACTION_PICK and send that video to the next Activity.

Here is my code:

```
R.id.imageViewVideo -> {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 32) {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null) // It shows the videos alone
                intent.type = "video/*"
                resultLauncher.launch(intent)
            } else {
            requestPermission()
            }
        }

private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            val videoUri: Uri = data?.data!!
            Log.i("videoUri", videoUri.toString()) // content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000000024/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/1940625115
            val videoPath = parsePath(videoUri)
            if (videoPath != null) {
                Log.i("videoPath", videoPath) 
 /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20231115_163657.mp4
                Log.i("videoPath22", videoUri.path.toString()) /-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/1000000024/ORIGINAL/NONE/video/mp4/1940625115
            }
           

            val intent = Intent(this@Camera2VideoFragment.requireContext(), SelectVideoActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("path", videoPath)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

Next Activity File:

```
val source = File(intent!!.getStringExtra("path")!!)
                    copyFile(source, inputFile)
                    Log.i("input file ===", inputFile.toString())

@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun copyFile(sourceFile: File?, destFile: File) {
        try {
                if (!destFile.parentFile!!.exists()) destFile.parentFile!!.mkdirs()
                if (!destFile.exists()) {
                    destFile.createNewFile()
                }
                var source: FileChannel? = null
                var destination: FileChannel? = null

                source = FileInputStream(sourceFile).channel
                destination = FileOutputStream(destFile).channel
                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size())
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                Log.i("error","selectvideo ${e.message}")
            }finally {
//                source?.close()
//                destination?.close()
                initViews()
                setListener()
            }
    }
```

For the lowest version of Androids the path looks like below and it works fine

Filepath:

/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20231121_193407.mp4
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.packagename/files/app-name/1700718359149.mp4

Code:

```
private lateinit var inputFile: File

     inputFile =
                File(getExternalFilesDir("app-mnme")!!.absolutePath.plus("/" + "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4"))
```